# How to Read Multiple Lines of input file for arithmetic yacc program?

Tags: yacc, lex

I am new to compilers and learning to make calculator that inputs multiple line equations (one equation each line) from a .txt file. And I am facing the problem of segmentation fault.

**YACC Code :**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define YYSTYPE int    /* the attribute type for Yacc's stack */ 
extern int yylval;     /* defined by lex, holds attrib of cur token */
extern char yytext[]; /* defined by lex and holds most recent token */
extern FILE * yyin;    /* defined by lex; lex reads from this file   */
%}

%token  NUM

%%

Begin : Line           
  | Begin Line     
  ;
Line  : Calc                 {printf("%s",$$);    }
  ;
Calc  : Expr                 {printf("Result = %d\n",$1);}
Expr  : Fact  '+'  Expr      { $$ = $1 + $3;    }
  | Fact  '-'  Expr      { $$ = $1 - $3;    }
  | Fact  '*'  Expr      { $$ = $1 * $3;    }
  | Fact  '/'  Expr      { $$ = $1 / $3;    }
  | Fact                 { $$ = $1;         }
  | '-' Expr             { $$ = -$2;        }
  ;
Fact  : '(' Expr ')'         { $$ = $2;         }
  | Id                   { $$ = $1;         }
  ;
Id    : NUM                  { $$ = yylval;     }
  ;

%%

void yyerror(char *mesg); /* this one is required by YACC */

main(int argc, char* *argv){
char ch;
if(argc != 2) {printf("useage:  calc filename \n"); exit(1);}
if( !(yyin = fopen(argv[1],"r")) ){ 
       printf("cannot open file\n");exit(1);
 }
yyparse();
}

void yyerror(char *mesg){
    printf("Bad Expression : %s\n", mesg);
    exit(1); /* stop after the first error */
}
```

**LEX Code :**

```
%{
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "y.tab.h"  
 int yylval; /*declared extern by yacc code. used to pass info to yacc*/  
%}

letter  [A-Za-z]
digit   [0-9]
num     ({digit})*
op      "+"|"*"|"("|")"|"/"|"-"
ws      [ \t\n]
other   .

%%

{ws}    {  /* note, no return */  }
{num}   {  yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUM;}
{op}    {  return yytext[0];}
{other} {  printf("bad%cbad%d\n",*yytext,*yytext); return  '?'; }

%%
/* c functions called in the matching section could go here */
```

I am trying to print the expression along with result.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your parser, you have:

```
Line  : Calc                 {printf("%s",$$);    }
```

Now `$$` is the semantic value which the rule is computing, and you haven't assigned anything to it. So it would not be unreasonable to assume that it is undefined, which would be bad, but in fact it does have a value because of the default rule `$$ = $1;`. All the same, it would be much more readable to write

```
printf("%s", $1);
```

But that's not correct, is it? After all, you have

```
#define YYSTYPE int
```

so all semantic types are integers. But you're telling `printf` that `$1` is a string (`%s`). `printf` will believe you, so it will go ahead and try to dereference the `int` as though it were a `char*`, with predictable results (i.e., a segfault).

You are probably using a compiler which is clever enough to notice the fact that you are trying to print an `int` with a `%s` format code. But either you haven't asked the compiler to help you or you are ignoring its advice.

*Always* compile with warnings enabled. If you are using gcc or clang, that means putting `-Wall` in the command line. (If you are using some other compiler, find out how to produce warnings. It will be documented.) And then read the warnings and fix them before trying to run the program.

---

There are several other errors and/or questionable practices in your code. Your grammar is inaccurate (why do you use `fact` as the left-hand operand of every operator?), and despite your comment, your lexical scanner ignores newline characters, so there is no way the parser can know whether expressions are one per line, two per line, or spread over multiple lines; that will make it hard to use the calculator as a command-line tool.

There is no need to define the lex macro `digit`; (f)lex recognizes the Posix character class `[[:digit:]]` (and others, [documented here](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns)) automatically. Nor is it particularly useful to define the macro `num`. Overuse of lex macros makes your program harder to read; it is usually better to just write the patterns out in place:

```
[[:digit:]]+       { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUM; }
```

which would be more readable and less work both for you and for anyone reading your code. (If your professor or tutor disagrees, I'd be happy to discuss the matter with them directly.)

Comment: rici i updated the Fact thing with Expr and now when I compiles it yacc code it succeeds but gives 20 shift/reduce conflicts message. I am able to get output but not the expression in .txt  For Eg : 2+3*(-7) is in .txt but when i write file reader code it throws yyerror message.

Comment: @nikul: please don't change your question after it has been answered. SO is intended to be a repository of questions and answers; when you change your question, you invalidate the answers, and then the information has no value to anyone else. If an answer helps you, you can vote for it and/or accept it; if it doesn't you can downvote it or ignore it, but in either case if you have another question, ask it as another question.

Comment: so sorry I am new to this site i didn't know.

Comment: @Nikul, No worries. Do feel free to ask a new question with your new problem, but it is always good to try to solve things yourself. You might want to take a look at the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Examples) which has example calculators and an explanation of precedence rules.